# IIS 10 manager - missing options in certificates pane

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

In IIS 10 on a Win 2019 server, I just created the Centralized Certificate Store.

How do I generate a CSR?
The "Generate CSR Request" option is missing.

[image]

Comment: the actions menu is context specific, what is selected in left hand connections pane?

Comment: I clicked on the server itself, next Centralized Certificates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"next Centralized Certificates" is wrong. You should click "Server Certificates".

Comment: Thanks Lex. This was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Server Certificates:

In the center menu, click the Server Certificates icon under the Security section near the bottom.

[image]

Select Create a New Certificate:

[image]

Enter your CSR details:

In the Distinguished Name Properties window, enter in the required CSR details and then click Next.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ding Peng. This was indeed the problem. I clicked on centralized server certificates.